# gem install nio4r -v 2.0.0 fails on windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to setup rails on windows 10 but I keep encountering an issue while attempting to install the nio4r gem.

```
C:\>gem install nio4r -v 2.0.0
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nio4r:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:      
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-2.0.0/ext/nio4r
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170317-11700-9smes9.rb extconf.rb
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for sys/select.h... no
checking for poll.h... no
checking for sys/epoll.h... no
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking for port.h... no
checking for sys/resource.h... no
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/nio4r-2.0.0/mkmf.log

current directory:   
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-2.0.0/ext/nio4r
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\ "DESTDIR=" clean
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

current directory:     
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-2.0.0/ext/nio4r
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\ "DESTDIR="
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.


make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in  
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-2.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to 
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/nio4r-2.0.0/gem_make.out
```

Initially, I attempted to avoid using the "railsinstaller" for windows but I ended up trying it thinking it may have a workaround for this unfortunately it did not and I still have the same issue.

Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Comment: Looks to me as though the installer has an issue with the space in `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\ "DESTDIR="` 
->
`'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal...`

if `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\` is in the `%PATH%` exactly like that you can change it to something like `C:\PROGRA~1\GnuWin32\bin\`

Comment: I actually tried that and it wasn’t the issue. Whatever it is seems to be resolved now as I successfully installed everything a couple weeks ago.

Comment: glad you got it working

Comment: As am I! My apologies for not marking it I forgot entirely about this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developers seemingly have fixed this issue as everything went through for me the last time I tried this some
 weeks ago!